# Real Analysis HW: Proving some f(N) is countable

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to learn real analysis from this website: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/

I have been trying to complete all the homework problems, and I have been spending a long time trying to rack up a proof to one of the questions:

*Let $Y$ be a set and let $f:\mathbb{N}\to Y$ be a function. Then $f(\mathbb{N})$ is at most countable.*

The question also comes with a hint, although it hasn't helped me very much:

*The basic problem is that f is not assumed to be one-to-one. Define $A$ to be the set: 
$A := \{n \in \mathbb{N}: f(m) \neq f(n) \text{ for all } 0 \leq m < n\}$.
Prove that when $f$ is restricted to $A$, it becomes a bijection from $A$ to $f(\mathbb{N})$. Then use proposition 2.*

I'm probably missing something, but I don't think f isn't necessarily a bijection from $A$ to $f(\mathbb{N})$. From the definition of a bijection, $f:A \to f(\mathbb{N})$ means that for every $a \in A$, there must be exactly one $b \in f(\mathbb{N})$ so $f(a)=b$. However, if you choose any element of $A$, let's say 3, $f(3)$, then choose $f(3)$ from $f(\mathbb{N})$, you get $f(3)=f(3)$. However, $f(\mathbb{N})$ isn't necessarily one-to-one; if $f(3)=f(5)$, you could also choose $f(5)$ from $f(\mathbb{N})$, defeating the statement that there is exactly one $b \in f(N)$ so $f(a)=b$.

I know $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ form a bijection; since $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, they have the same cardinality (from a proposition 2 referenced in the hint, it is proven in the text). I think that's what the last sentence of the hint is referring to. Although that bijection isn't necessarily f, from what I can tell.

I'm pretty lost at what to do, there are only two questions from this particular homework sheet answered, neither of them this one, and I couldn't find this problem after some searching around. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: "if f(3)=f(5), you could also choose f(5) from f(N)" but $5 \not\in A$. The point of the set $A$ is that it removes all duplicate values of $f$.

Comment: I'm not saying 5 is in set A, I'm taking f(5) from the set f(N). I'm saying that if f(3)=f(5), there are two elements from the set f(N) that equal f(3); f(3) and f(5). Thus, for one element a in set A, a=3, there exists at least two elements b from the set f(N), f(3) and f(5), so that f(a)=b. This contradicts the one-to-one nature of a bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that the natural numbers are countable and $f$ is a function, which means that there are no $y_1,y_2\in Y$ with $y_1\neq y_2$ such that $f(n)=y_1$ and $f(n)=y_2$.

What does this tell you about the amount of elements $Y$ can have at most?

Comment: Huh, so there is at most a one-to-one correspondence with the elements of Y (or f(N), which is equivalent) and the natural numbers. Thanks :)